# Solving Autofac issue Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member GetService

Tags: autofac

I've got an ASP.NET MVC application using Autofac.

I've added the appropriate packages via:

```
Install-Package Autofac
Install-Package Autofac.Mvc4
```

When I ran the web application, this error was throw:

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I had installed Autofac for MVC 4 when the project type was actually MVC 5.

To solve this, I ran `Uninstall-Package Autofac.Mvc4` and

```
Install-Package Autofac.Mvc5
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Having separate ASP.NET and MVC versions can get pretty confusing now that they're advertising ASP.NET 5.

Comment: Facing the same issue, but I cannot install Autofac.Mvc5 . 
Error: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Autofac 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with 
that framework

Comment: Also getting the same as @user3014311 now.  Uninstalled all autofac and went from start. All projects targetting 4.5.

Comment: This error is due to the target framework. In order to install Autofac 4 the project must target .NET Framework 4.6+