# ASP.net MVC 4 and Autofac error - Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am getting some strange error while configuring Autofac on ASP.MVC 4. I have worked with Autofac on MVC 4 on many other projects successfully. This MVC project is in .Net 4.5.2 and I am referencing the following Autofac libraries from nuget:

Autofac version=3.5.2

Autofac.Mvc4 version=3.1.0

The error that I am getting is:

"Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden."

The weird thing is that my code is even not called that this error is fired!! My code is as below:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        try
        {
            AutofacDependencyResolverHelper.RegisterAutofac();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Write(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

    }


     public class AutofacDependencyResolverHelper
{
    public static void RegisterAutofac()
    {
        var container = GetContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    public static IContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("Core.Infrastructure"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("Core.GenericRepository"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("Core.Common"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("CRM.Interfaces"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("CRM.Data"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("CRM.Dtos"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("CRM.Entities"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("CRM.Business"));

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray()).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.Load("CRM.Web.Mvc4"));
        var container = builder.Build();
        return container;
    }
}
```

Not sure what this error is? Any comments will be appreciated. I have found some other questions but they are related to MVC5:

[Solving Autofac issue Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member GetService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696246/solving-autofac-issue-inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-membe)

**Updated with full config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="4.2.7" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Autofac.Mvc4" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole packages.config?

Comment: Hi, updaated the above post with full .config details

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the issue. Even though it was an MVC4 application I added reference to Autofac MVC5 using nuget and that sorted out the issue. Ie:

package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="3.3.4" targetFramework="net452"

Instead of:

package id="Autofac.Mvc4" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net46"

Strange.but it worked!

Comment: If you look at your MVC reference, it's version 5.2.3 - MVC 5, not MVC 4. That's why it was fixed. Glad it's working for you now!